# url is not redirecting properly?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have created some page but the problem is that the url is not redrecting to the file I want.I have created some tags and mention in  tag. now when I click on any tag it is not redirecting to tag.php, it is linking to main.php.
why it is so I don't understand.

here is my .htaccess file

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/main.php?authchar=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/author.php? authchar=$1&authorname=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/quotes.php?authchar=$1&authorname=$2&authorquote=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotes/tag.php?authchar=$1&authorname=$2&authorquote=$3&tag=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: my url is linking to some other file instead of tag.php....now see the pattern it was by mistake

Comment: http://localhost/quotes/authors/history.html where history is a tag.

Comment: i have made SEO Friendly url.

Comment: yes it is the directory and .htaccess is placed in it

Answer (score 0):

You can use these rules in `/quotes/.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /quotes/

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)\.html$ main.php?authchar=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ author.php?authchar=$1&authorname=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ quotes.php?authchar=$1&authorname=$2&authorquote=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ tag.php?authchar=$1&authorname=$2&authorquote=$3&tag=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: sorry I dont understand should I make new .htaccess

Comment: bro i did but nothing happens yet..no difference at all

Comment: bro it is redirecting to some other page..ya i m doing what you said. but i m sure my engine is on...

Comment: bro that page is my main.php. the url i gave you before should redirect to tag.php and not main.php

Comment: do u want me to put my code of all the three files.

Comment: please state me something that matches tag.php

Comment: Then change first rule to `RewriteRule ^authors/([^/]*)\.html$ tag.php?authchar=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: then what about main.php

Comment: That's your file, if you don't know the requirement then who can help you.

Comment: main.php is equally important as tag.php

Comment: I will have to stop responding to endless comments here. You need to **edit the question** and wirte **each and every URL** scheme that you want to support and how it should be handled internally.